# Combine two queries into a single query without relationship

Tags: apex, soql

So i have Two Queries

1. `SELECT Id, DurableId FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId ='Student__c' AND QualifiedAPIName = 'Hobby__c'`

What i want to do is take the **DurableId** from the above Query and add in to Second query below

2. `SELECT DurableId,EntityParticleId,Id,IsActive,IsDefaultValue,Label,ValidFor,Value FROM PicklistValueInfo where EntityParticleId =_DurableId_From_First_Query`

I know it is possible in apex code But,

**Is is possible to make it a single SQOL query, how can i achieve this in a single query** ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, using the [IN operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm). use the 1st query in the where clause of the 2nd query, like this:

```
SELECT DurableId... FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticleId In 
(SELECT DurableId FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId ='Student__c' AND QualifiedAPIName = 'Hobby__c' )
```

Comment: This (semi-joins) is the general answer to this sort of problem. However, from what I've tried, it does not work in this particular case.

Comment: Thank You @Json, but i have tried doing the same but it does not works.